# Ruby merge two arrays of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge, hash

I have the following two Ruby arrays which each are made up of hashes:

```
arr1 = [{:a=>"6884", :b=>true}, {:a=>"8456", :b=>false}, {:a=>"5631", :b=>false}]
arr2 = [{:c=>"6884"}, {:c=>"8023"}, {:c=>"9837"}]
```

I want to merge each hash of `arr2` into each hash of `arr1` that is at the same index. So the final array would look like:

```
arr3 = [{:a=>"6884", :b=>true, :c=>"6884"}, {:a=>"8456", :b=>false, :c=>"8023"}, {:a=>"5631", :b=>false, :c=>"9837"}]
```

I am sure there is a nice Ruby way of doing this, but I haven't quite figured it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input

```
arr1 = [{ :a => "6884", :b => true }, { :a => "8456", :b => false }, { :a => "5631", :b => false }]
arr2 = [{ :c => "6884" }, { :c => "8023" }, { :c => "9837" }]
```

Code

```
p arr1.zip(arr2).map { |h1, h2| h1.merge(h2) }
```

Output

```
[{:a=>"6884", :b=>true, :c=>"6884"}, {:a=>"8456", :b=>false, :c=>"8023"}, {:a=>"5631", :b=>false, :c=>"9837"}]
```

Comment: Currently, this is basically a code-only answer. You might want to add some explanation or at least one or two links to the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
arr1.each_index.map { |i| arr1[i].merge(arr2[i]) }
  #=> [{:a=>"6884", :b=>true, :c=>"6884"},
  #    {:a=>"8456", :b=>false, :c=>"8023"},
  #    {:a=>"5631", :b=>false, :c=>"9837"}]
```

This avoids the creation of the temporary array `arr1.zip(arr2)`, but it  should only be considered (to save memory) if the arrays are quite large, as it has the disadvantage that if does not read as well as answers employing `arr1.zip(arr2)` (or `[arr1, arr2].transpose`).

Note that, without a block, [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) returns an enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```rb
arr1 = [{:a=>"6884", :b=>true}, {:a=>"8456", :b=>false}, {:a=>"5631", :b=>false}]
arr2 = [{:c=>"6884"}, {:c=>"8023"}, {:c=>"9837"}]

arr1.zip(arr2).map{|a| a[0].merge(a[1])}
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner: `.map { |a, b| a.merge(b) }`. Edit: or with the new syntax, `.map { _1.merge(_2) }`

Comment: @Dogbert, next time please warn me when you are going to use the "new syntax" as it makes me feel slightly nauseous.